# How to switch TabBarControllerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

hope u can help me!
I've made an iPhoneApplication navigated by a tabbarcontroller.
The problem is, that I want to change the selected tab in a method!
Something like: `[self changeSelectedTabBarController: 4]; ...`
Is there an easy way to do this? I've already searched the whole www for an answer but I'm not getting any help there!

Thanks

P.S. I'm quite new to Xcode and Objective-C and maybe not getting all of what you answer^^

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:4];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:4];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390619/complex-multiview-iphone-ios/5390754#5390754)
Just not forget to implement init() in each viewController.